# Discord Bots with Youtube API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Hi I was wondering how to search videos with A discord bot (http://discordapp.com/) I have code to trigger it and give it a variable but I need a api to search and return results with

Comment: what did you tried ?

Comment: we don't make your homework for you, we just reverse your code to find what is wrong.

Comment: @joebean what discord api library are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the YouTube Data API v3's `search` endpoint to search through YouTube. More about that, including code samples, [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list).